# ExtJS Panel Inheritance/Base class

Tags: extjs

I am trying to create my own Date/Time field. I know there are a few that others have made, I'm making my own .

My question is as follows. I want to create a new object, DateTime, which extends Ext.Panel. I specify some properties for width, height, etc but I also specify the values for the items property which will contain a date field and a time field. When I try to actually instantiate the created object, I get an error saying "Object or property not supported". When I go into the error, it seems that the items collection throws an error The code is as follows:

```
var dateField = new AppealDate({
    id: 'dateField',
    tabIndex: 0,
    fieldLabel: '',
    msgTarget: 'under'
});
var timeField = new Ext.form.TimeField({
    id: 'timeField',
    tabIndex: 0,
    fieldLabel: '',
    msgTarget: 'under'
});
var DateTime = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    id: '',
    xtype: 'panel',
    fieldLabel: '',
    layout: 'table',
    layoutConfig: {
        columns: 2
    },
    items: [dateField, timeField]
});

var dateTimeField = new DateTime(); //this throws an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is missing initComponent. You also need to render the panel somewhere.

```
DateTime = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
     initComponent: function() {
         // define dateField, timeField here.
         this.dateField = new AppealDate({
             id: 'dateField',
             msgTarget: 'under'
         });
          this.timeField = new Ext.form.TimeField({
             id: 'timeField',
             msgTarget: 'under'
         });
         Ext.apply(this, {
             items: [this.dateField, this.timeField]
         });
         DateTime.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
     }
});

var dateTimeField = new DateTime();
dateTimeField.render(Ext.get('someDiv'));
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is great, I get a faster response back from StackOverflow then I do from the actual ExtJS support which we're paying for.

Comment: Just curious, why do I have to call initComponent and use Ext.apply within it to accomplish this?  Why wouldn't my original post have worked?  Would like to know so I can keep in mind for future base classes.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment outside of your direct question, "DateTime" is a terrible name for a Panel subclass.  You want someone coming along later to know what kind of class they are dealing with -- "DateTimeField" would be much better, based on how you're using it (although that implies a `Field` subclass as explained below...).

However, note that another potential issue since you are intending to use this Panel as a Field is that a FormPanel is going to expect its form fields to support the `Ext.form.Field` interface, which your "field" will not (i.e., you won't be able to add your DateTime object into a form's `items` config).  So if your goal is to create a truly reusable component that can be treated as a Field, you're going to want to add methods like `getValue`, `setValue`, `markInvalid`, etc. that internally interact with your constituent fields.  It's not a trivial task to get it all working smoothly.

(Not sure if this is your goal, but thought I would mention it since I've gone down this road myself).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  You're right, not as simple as I had thought.  I had to implement all the common expected methods of a field for this panel.